Notation for empirical measure (Dirac measure)
I am writing a paper in an area that I am relatively unfamiliar with, and I am after suggestions concerning notation.
Here the notion of empirical measure is introduced in the paper .
In the notation, x^j are points in space, but the other two arguments at the foot of the Dirac symbol are functions in a Banach space. As you see, the occurrence of superscripts and subscripts at the foot of the Dyrac symbol is really awful (the formula has other typesetting oddities too, but I know how to solve them).
Have you come across papers or books in which the empirical measure is written differently, so that x^j and its relatives don't appear as a subscript?
Thank you

Sorry but in the current form this is off-topic. Math.SE might be more appropriate.

I mildly disagree, because this is a matter of typographical convention not mathematics, but I have posted it there.

@DanieleAvitabile It really is not, LaTeX does not decide on the notation being used it only provide the tools to do so. Thus, the notational tradition is purely mathematical and not typographical.

@daleif, this must have escaped us for 20 years at the Italian Tex Users Group (https://www.guitex.org/home/en/forum/index) where there is even a dedicated forum on notational aspects specifically. But don't worry, I've asked it elsewhere
